# Sharepoint Online - Migrated events are NOT showing up in the view

Tags: sharepoint-online

We have migrated the content from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint online (SPO - Office 365) using Sharepoint migration tool.  Issue is with the calendar events which are migrated. they are NOT showing up in the events view when placed on a modern page. they do show in the calendar list but NOT the a page where we add a view for that calendar. can somebody help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you add Events web part in the modern page?

Events web part does not show events in the calendar list.